# CSS background color is not applied consistently to visited links. CSS added by GM_addStyle

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors, greasemonkey

I'm noticing some odd behavior with CSS added by `GM_addStyle()`. I have the following userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Reddit
// @namespace   http://example.com
// @include     http://www.reddit.com/
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle("a:visited { background-color: yellow !important; }");
```

Now, I'd expect the behavior to either work for all links or work for no links (due to the security patch), but what I get is an inconsistent behavior in that it works for some link, but not other.

[image: Works for hot/top/wiki, but not any other links]

Could anyone explain the above behavior for me?

Comment: Heh, what's more bizarre is if you apply `color` instead of `background-color` it works as expected, applying the color to all visited links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Privacy and the :visited selector at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector):

> Only the following properties can be applied to visited links:
>
> - color
> - background-color
> - border-color (and its sub-properties)
> - outline-color
> - The color parts of the fill and stroke properties
>
> In addition, even for the properties you can set for visited links, **you won't be able to change the transparency between unvisited and visited links**, as you otherwise would be able to using rgba() or hsla() color values or the transparent keyword.

Apparently, this means, in Firefox, that in order for you to *change* the background color, the link must first have a background (which you can't add using the `:visited` selector).  So set the background before trying to style visited links' background color.

This works for me:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Reddit, style visited links
// @include     http://www.reddit.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle (
      /* For precision, only prime the desired links, that don't
        otherwise have a BG.
      */
      "a.title { background: white; }"
    + "a:visited { background-color: yellow !important; }"
);
```

Note that I just "primed" the links that I was explicitly interested in, that didn't already have a background.  Hence the `a.title {...` instead of `a {...`.

---

Also note that for just changing styles, [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) is usually a better bet (performance and ease of setup).

Comment: Why don't we observe the same behavior when using `color` then? The links in the body are also "unprimed", so wouldn't we expect them to not turn yellow according to this documentation?

Comment: Because all of the links already have a color.  They don't need to be primed for that.  Not sure if transparency matters for that, either, since it wouldn't effect things like BG images loading.  Plus, plenty of links on those pages ARE already given a BG by Reddit CSS, so you don't need to "prime" them.